# How to group by diapasons?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have got a table 'payments'

```
user_id amount
1       300
1       100
2       100
2       100
3       10
4       200
```

What query should I make to display result by groups:

```
diapason       number
0 -10          0
10 - 100       1
100 -200       3
more than 200  2
```

I think I should use 'having'?

Comment: You gotta learn how to search before posting. There are lots of answers on SO to this problem.

Comment: @V.G. the issue with the proposed duplicate is that it doesn't return ranges where there are no values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of query you could use a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT '0-10' as diapason, SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number FROM payments
UNION
SELECT '10-100', SUM(CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 10 AND 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM payments
UNION
SELECT '100-200', SUM(CASE WHEN amount BETWEEN 100 AND 199 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM payments
UNION
SELECT 'more than 200', SUM(CASE WHEN amount >= 200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM payments
```

Output:

```
diapason        number
0-10            0
10-100          1
100-200         3
more than 200   2
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa48c4/2)